# Specifying granularity of labels with datetimeaxis in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

I've been trying for a while to set the number of labels being shown with a datetimeaxis being used for the y-axis.  Unfortunately, I'm not able to get the desired behaviour.

I'd like to have the y-axis separated into days (i.e. a tick on the axis for each day).  However, it is spacing them out one week at a time.  I have tried setting labelUnits and minorTickUnits to "days" but no joy.

```
<mx:DateTimeAxis id="vStepAxis" labelUnits="days" minorTickUnits="days" parseFunction="ParseDateForAxis" title="Date/Time"/>
```

Any ideas?  All help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
<mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
            <mx:AxisRenderer
...
canDropLabels="false"
```

Comment: I didn't even know it was possible to post an empty answer.

Comment: @AShelly: If you post markup without indenting it, it won't be displayed because it lacks code formatting.